# Unsupported compression type in ERDAS imagine Software

Tags: erdas-imagine

Am trying to load a Landsat band but I keep getting the error of unsupported compression type, what might be the problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your data is using a compression type that's not supported by ERDAS Imagine.  Please provide more detail about the data. What format, where you got it and preferably a `gdalinfo` report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

experienced similar issue when I downloaded Landsat 8 and 9 images from Usgs archives using Collection 2 level 2 and also collection 2, level 1.
the problem is caused compression type used in storages,

here is my solution process to the problem:

```
 - Unzip your l8 or whatever landsat image it is using band zipper or any other extractor
 - open Erdas;
   using "manage data" => 'import data' tool:
 - change data format to GeoTiff,
 - input your band in the 'input' option
```

[image: pop up error when loading the band, press OK to continue]

```
note: when you still get an error saying unsupported format, click **OK** 
to continue 

 - set out location for your output and give a name for your band
 - click OK and ok on the next step, wait for process to complete.

 - Done! you can now load your imported band without any problem
```

for layer stacking, you need to repeat the process for each needed band